# What is an accetable delay for ETH transaction during congestion

Tags: etherscan

I have withdrawn Eth from coinexchange 2 days ago. They have said it was successfully processed from their site and due to congestion may take a while.I have checked block explorer and it can't find the transaction. What would you experts consider a reasonable time for the transaction to appear.